# word processor document - file format compatible with rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, ms-word, word-processor

I'd like to write my terms and conditions using a word processor, save it and easily embed the file in my Rails application. Nothing fancy, just have paragraphs, and bold (and regular) fonts. Which is a file format that can be easily used to display a formatted text with Rails? I don't want to have to deal with a lot of gems, dependencies, etc for some simple formatting.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to do normal html formatting, because all view files are .html.erb so I don't think you can copy your style/format from editors unless you have a html text editor.

I suggest that you should write it in a plain text and later add html tags for formatting, also by this method you don't have to deal with any gems or dependencies. You can also use css to make it better styled.